# How to change binary to string

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-phone-7

The coding like

```
decimal prodprice = Convert.ToDecimal(NavigationContext.QueryString["Price"]);
```

then what should i put for

```
Binary image = Convert.ToByte(NavigationContext.QueryString["Image"]);
```

I had error at Convert.ToByte.

Comment: Which error did you get?

Comment: Is it base4string? and are your getting it in query string?

Comment: It show me error cannot convert byte to binary..Image at my Sql database it varbinary. then what should i put it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am just going to assume you get your "Image" querystring as a Hex string (0-F digits). If so, you can convert it into a byte array first. An example (not the most efficient one but it should work):

```
string data = "0A0B0C0F1102"; // example data
if (data.Length % 2 != 0) { data = "0" + data; } 

byte[] result = new byte[data.Length / 2];
for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i += 2) {
    result[i/2] = Convert.ToByte(data.Substring(i, 2), 16);
}
Binary image = result;
```